# Object list serialization problem

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

i have a very specific problem with the mapping of an xml file to an object.

Here is the XML example file:

```
<spyce>
   <reference name="test">
      <Data id="1">10</Data>
      <Data id="2">20</Data>
   </reference>
</Spyce>
```

Here are my mapping classes:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("spyce")]
public class Spyce
{
    private Reference reference;
    [XmlElement("reference")]
    public Reference Reference
    {
        get { return reference; }
        set { reference = value; }
    }
}

[XmlRoot("reference")]
public class Reference
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string name;

    [XmlArray]
    private List<Data> dataList;
    [XmlElement("data")]
    public List<Data> DataList
    {
        get { return dataList; }
        set { dataList = value; }
    }
}

public class Data
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string id;

    private int dataValue;
    [XmlElement("data")]
    public int DataValue
    {
        get { return dataValue; }
        set { dataValue= value; }
    }
}
```

The serialization goes well i get an Spyce object. In this object is the Reference object with the variable name and the list DataList. An here comes the problem => the Data objects in the list have a variable id but DataValue stands always at 0.

How can i handle this?

With best regards.

Spike

Comment: Are you using XmlSerializer or how you serialize/deserialize the objects?

Comment: i am using the xmlserializer yes, Reniuz solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change attribute to XmlText:

```
[XmlText(Type=typeof(int))]
public int DataValue
```

Comment: Thx for the fast answers. @Reniuz: thx i have totally forget that it can be a kind of text typ. Normaly it does not make problem. With best regards.